# Set Row Tag Value when Using Binding Source for Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I am trying to set the value of the row `Tag` when using a binding source.

Is this possible to do when the binding source's `DataSource` is set? Could the `Tag` be a value in the list that is being set as the `DataSource`?

I know that I can iterate over the rows and set the `Tag` value afterwards, but I am wondering if this could be done when setting the `DataSource`.

Any information on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot set a Property of an object that doesn't exist at that time. I don't se why you should, since you're saying hat the value is part of the DataSource. If you don't want t show that value, hide the DGV's Column bound to that data column.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the feedback. I am wondering if there is a property or flag that I can set so that a bound object's property is assigned to the row's `Tag`?

Answer (score 0):

The binded object is DataBoundItem property:

`datagridview.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem`

Regards,